# Laravel 5.6: sending email to BCC without adding email in TO()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to send email to only bcc() without to().
When I tried, I got error

Error Information.

> URL: http://example.com Parameters: [] Request Name: Request Method:
> GET Line Number: 309 File:
> /var/www/html/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php
> Client IP: 127.0.0.1 HTTP Referer: Is Secure: Is Ajax: userAgent:
> Symfony content: Error Message: Whoops! There was an error.
> ErrorException (E_WARNING) Illegal string offset 'address'
> ErrorException thrown with message "Illegal string offset 'address'"
> Stacktrace: #38 ErrorException in
> /var/www/html/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php:309
> #37 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions:handleError in /var/www/html/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php:309

Sending email to all bcc without using to

Comment: You can't send an email without a "to" address

Comment: Is there any way to do so?

Comment: no. there is not.

Comment: You can send it to yourself in the "to" address, and put all other addresses in bcc

Comment: Unfortunately Your question's solution is not possible. you have to add `to` while sending email

Comment: Currently it's possible to send emails without a to like: address $message->bcc($recipients)->subject($subject);   just in case people reach this answer like I did